# Finding String Length of one node of linked list

Tags: c, list, hyperlink

I am traversing linked list. I just want to find `strlen` of each node of linked list.

**Here is node:**

```
    struct node  
    {
       long HuffmanCodes;
       struct node *next;
    };
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *current = NULL;
```

**Now Traversing and finding `strlen` of each node of linked list.**

```
 int HuffmanCodeslength = 0;
 struct node *ptr = head;
 while(ptr != NULL)
 {
     HuffmanCodeslength = strlen(ptr->HuffmanCodes);
     ptr = ptr->next;   
 }
 ptr = head;
```

> I don't know

```
strlen(ptr->HuffmanCodes)
```

> is possible or not.
>   **When I run this code. It stopped working on runtime.
>   Where is the mistake?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just think about this for a second.  You are asking whether doing `strlen(ptr->HuffmanCodes)` and assigning that value to an `int` is possible, when `ptr->HuffmanCodes` gives a `long` integer.  Why not just test this out (and pay attention to the warnings)?

Say we have the simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  long myLongInt = 4873874;
  printf("%zd\n", strlen(myLongInt));
  return 0;
}
```

Since basically, you are trying to find the string length of a `long` (and `strlen` is normally used with strings).

Here is what happens when we try to compile this:

```
user@user Stack Overflow $ gcc dynamic_testing.c
dynamic_testing.c:6:26: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'long' to parameter of type 'const char *'
      [-Wint-conversion]
  printf("%zd\n", strlen(myLongInt));
                         ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/string.h:82:28: note: passing argument to parameter here
size_t   strlen(const char *);
                            ^
1 warning generated.
```

Clearly, there is a mismatch since `strlen` expects a `const char *` and we are passing a `long`.  You cannot do this.  Furthermore, the output:

```
user@user Stack Overflow $ ./a.out
Segmentation fault: 11
user@user Stack Overflow $
```

Then you try to assign this value to an `int` when in the first place it causes a segmentation fault.

Quite simply: `strlen(ptr->HuffmanCodes)` is not a legal statement.  I don't understand why you are trying to get the string length of a `long int`.

Comment: @Mohit Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` is used only for strings/character array.

If you want to find out the length of each node than you have to use sizeof(struct node);

or to find the sizeof `HuffmanCodes` use `sizeof(ptr->HuffmanCodes);`